# Compare length of list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am asking you because I don't know where to turn anymore. After 2 hours of searching I came up with nothing.

So basically I am writing program that receive different variables and then append units to that variables.

Now everything is store in dictionary that have variables for keys and units for values. So my question is how can we compare the first list in dictionary with other lists that are in it?

I need these because length of units must be the same...

Here is my code:

```
data = {}
def test():
    variable = input("Please enter the name of variable: ")
    data[variable]=[]
    while True:
        unit = input("Enter unit: ")
        if unit == "":
            break
        data[variable].append(unit)
        a = len(data[variable])
    while True:
        start_again = input("Add another value to dictionary?(y/n: ")
        start_again = start_again.lower()
        if start_again == "d":
            test()
        elif start_again == "n":
            break
    print(data)
test()
```

I am a beginner so dont be too hard on me.

I am looking forward to answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
data = {}
def test():
    while True:
        variable = input("Please enter the name of variable: ")
        new_list = []
        while True:
            unit = input("Enter unit: ")
            if unit == "":break
            new_list.append(unit)
```

Below you can compare a list that you are about to add to the dictionary with lists that are already in the dictionary:

```
        if data: # when the dictionary is not empty
            list_length = len(new_list)
            other_lengths = [len(item) for item in data.items()]
```

The other_length variable creates a list of the length of all the current lists in the dictionary. You could do some kind of comparison at this point if you want or just add the new list and variable to you dictionary. Its up to you.

```
        else: # add new list and variable to empty dictionary
                data[variable]= new_list

        start_again = input("Add value to dictionary?(y/n): ").lower()
        if start_again== 'y':continue
        else:
            return (data) # returns dictionary
```

The return statement returns the dictionary so you can assign it to a variable, like below:

```
new_data = test()
new_data # calling this would return your dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I think that you missed the point. I need to save my variables and units for further usage. And also the size of the units is unknown and it is set, when you create your first variable.